# Reinitializing a variable in class ERROR?

Tags: java

```
public class PointMain{
   static int i=10;
   //i=20;      
    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
 }
```

After the line that `i=20` is written, it shows an error. why?

Answer (score 0):

An assignment such as `i=20;` must be inside some method or initialization block.

Comment: when we can declare and initialize at the beginning why cant we reinitialize why should we only re initialize in a method?

Comment: @deepakrao That's how the language in defined. It wouldn't make much sense to have multiple assignments to the same variable, since all assignments would be executd when the class is initialized, and the last assignment will override all the others. When you have an assignment inside a method, it is only executed when the method is called.

Answer (score 0):

you could do that, using static code. You need to put bracket around static code.

```
public class PointMain{
   static int i=10;
   static {
      i=20;  
   }    
    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
 }
```